# FOSUserBundle: Update entity after registration

Tags: symfony, entity, fosuserbundle

In order to register, users have to select a their account name created by my moderators. That means that a moderators have to create an account name before the user registers.

To do so, I made a first entity, let's call it "Member", that has a field "account". Then I added to this entity the boolean field "bound" that is set to false by default.

What I want to do is to set this field "bound" to **true** when someone registers after he selected his account name and fill the FOSUserBundle required fields (username, passwords, email...).

I tried to follow the documentation of "[overriding controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md)", but I'm getting an error (You have requested a non-existent service "fos_user.registration.form".) and this is where I'm stucked.

[Using controller events](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md) can maybe help me, but I do not know which is the best solution.

If anyone has a solution to my problem, I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should used the [controller event](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md) to hook after the registration process, and more specifically the
 REGISTRATION_COMPLETED event (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot :)
Although I used the event REGISTRATION_SUCCESS because for some reason, I couldn't register a new account...